# Vuevalidate async validation results to a loop

Tags: vuejs2, vue-validator

Am using [Vue Validate](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/)

i have the following in my vuevlidate

```
      validations: {
        user_form: {
            email: {required,email, isUnique(value) {
                    // standalone validator ideally should not assume a field is required
                    if (value === '') return true;
                    // simulate async call, fail for all logins with even length
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                       this.$http.post("v1/user-management/users/email-registeredi",{email:value}).then((res)=>{
                            console.log("res is ", res);
                            resolve(true);
                        },(err)=>{
                            reject(false)
                        })
                    })
                }},
            role: {required},
            password: {required}
        }
    },
```

The above creates an endless loop of http requests especially when it gets an error

Where am i going wrong

Comment: An endless loop of http requests implies that the `isUnique` function is called endlessly. I can't reproduce that with this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/4083p7r1o4). Can you edit the demo to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In case vue validate is not handling reject promise well and creating infinite loop.
You can try, `async await` for Vue validate's [isUnique](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/#sub-asynchronous-validation) with try and catch returning `false` on error,
something like this.

```
validations: {
 user_form: {
  email: {
    required,
    email,
    async isUnique (value) {
        if (value === '') return true
        try{
          const response = await this.$http.post("v1/user-management/users/email-registeredi",{email:value})
          return true;
        }
        catch(e){
          return false;
        }   
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use "new Promise" because vue-resource already do that. Try this:

```
validations: {
    user_form: {
        email: {required,email, isUnique(value) {
                // standalone validator ideally should not assume a field is required
                if (value === '') return true;
                // simulate async call, fail for all logins with even length

               return this.$http.post("v1/user-management/users/email-registeredi",{email:value}).then((res)=>{
                    console.log("res is ", res);
                    return true;
                },(err)=>{
                    return false;
                });
            }},
        role: {required},
        password: {required}
    }
},
```